# Emulating the default Ubuntu partitioning scheme

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, partition

When I install Ubuntu and tell it to use the first full disk, it creates the following partitions, numbered 1 and 5:

```
sda1 /
sda5 swap
```

When I create two partitions manually, the partitions are numbered 1 and 2:

```
sda1 /
sda2 swap
```

I believe this is because Ubuntu creates an extended partition, and then creates the swap partition in the new extended partition.

Using `fdisk` or `GParted` (or similar), how would one create a partition table exactly the same as the Ubuntu installer? How do I retain the default numbering style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify the swap partition as 'logical'.

The actual layout will be this:

```
sda1 # primary
sda2 { # extended
  sda5 # logical
}
```